# Databricks CLI - delete folder if exists

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli

Databricks throws an error when I try to delete a folder that doe not exist:

```
databricks workspace delete -r /Shared/myfolder
```

Error message:

```
Error: b'{"error_code":"RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST","message":"Path (/Shared/myfolder) doesn\'t exist."}'
```

So I would probably need to check if the folder exists before deleting it?

Pseudo code example:

```
if [ -d "/Shared/myfolder" ]; then databricks workspace delete -r /Shared/myfolder ; fi
```

How can I implement this using Databricks CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no separate function in the CLI (and REST API) to check existence of resource. You have two choices:

1. Just ignore the error - if you don't want to see it in the script, just add `> /dev/null` at the end of command
2. Use `ls` subcommand to check existence of directory, and then delete (but I personally don't see benefit from that). Something like this:

```sh
FOLDER=/Shared/myfolder
databricks workspace ls $FOLDER > /dev/null
RES=$?
if [ $RES -eq 0 ]; then
  databricks workspace delete -r $FOLDER
fi
```

I would personally go with first approach

Comment: Second choice makes my day, I have this as a step in azure pipeline and only with the second solution the pipeline will not fail which is what I was trying to achive. Really appreciate your help here, thanks!